# How do I increase the maximum number of outbound peers?

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers

How can I increase the maximum number of outbound peers bitcoin core can connect to? I can't seem to be able to connect to more than 10. I've tried using the `-maxconnections` flag but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: There's no option for doing this. You won't see any improvement in sync speed, transaction confirmation speed, and it doesn't meaningfully increase security or reliability by increasing the number of outbound transactions.

Comment: [The comment](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/109833/how-do-i-increase-the-maximum-number-of-outbound-peers#comment124606_109833) is an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Core will only make a limited number of outbound connections. In particular:

- Up to 10 outbound connections

  - 8 normal outbound connections
  - 2 block-only outbound connections
- Up to 8 manual connections (using `-addnode` command line, `addnode=` config line, or `addnode` RPC).

These limits cannot be changed without modifying the source code. In general, there is very little reason for doing so, as it doesn't increase confirmation speed, processing speed, or reliability. Early in Bitcoin's history there have been periods where the network ran out of connection slots (inbound-capable peers times the number of incoming connections they accept), so Bitcoin Core's developers are loathe to add features to go beyond the standard number.